# How to Display one variable and one constant value in zabbix trigger

Tags: zabbix

I would like to create a zabbix trigger with the available memory and total memory for a particular host. How is this possible with one trigger.My requirement is to have both available memory and the total memory listed in the action mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, you can use a trigger like this to check that available memory is less than 10% of the total:

```
{Template OS Linux:vm.memory.size[available].max(#3)} <
    0.1 * {Template OS Linux:vm.memory.size[total].last()}
```

In the action email, you can then reference item names, keys, and values like so:

```
Item values:

1. {ITEM.NAME1} ({HOST.NAME1}:{ITEM.KEY1}): {ITEM.VALUE1}
2. {ITEM.NAME2} ({HOST.NAME2}:{ITEM.KEY2}): {ITEM.VALUE2}
3. {ITEM.NAME3} ({HOST.NAME3}:{ITEM.KEY3}): {ITEM.VALUE3}
```

In the example above, `{ITEM.KEY1}` refers to `vm.memory.size[available]` and `{ITEM.KEY2}` refers to `vm.memory.size[total]`. Similarly for other macros. `{ITEM.KEY3}` will expand to `*UNKNOWN*`, because there is no third item in the trigger expression.

Such an email format comes with Zabbix 2.2 and Zabbix 2.4 by default.

Comment: May I know why this string 'max(#3)' used in the trigger.

Comment: Function "max(#3)" is used to prevent trigger flapping. If we would use "last()" there, then any time available memory would be less than 10%, the trigger would fire, even if available memory was in that state for only a short period of time. Function "max(#3)" makes the trigger fire only in case all last three item values for available memory are low. Perhaps, you would want to use something like "max(5m)" instead, which would make the trigger fire if available memory is low for the last 5 minutes.

Comment: Could you please define "not working"? The frontend does not allow you to save the expression and complains about "last()" not having an argument? If so, you are probably using an older version of Zabbix: just put "last(0)" there instead.